# Unable to correlate Kafka request - response using state store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a spring boot application build using Kafka streams which needs to integrate with an external application. So we have defined two topologies:

**1. Request topology:**

- A (`complex-type-key`, `string-value`) record arrives in the `input-topic`.
- From the `complex-type-key` we extract an unique `string-key` and store the `string-key` and the `string-value` in a state store (local and persistent)
- We transform the `string-value` in a `string-request` and write the (`string-key`, `string-request`) record to the external application we are integrating with

**2. Response topology:**

- We receive the (`string-key`, `string-response`) record from the external application in our response topic
- We look up `string-key` in the state store and want to retrieve the original `string-value`
- Based on the original `string-value` and `string-request` we do some processing and forward the original (`complex-type-key`, `string-value`) to `outbound-topic-1` or `outbound-topic-2`

All works fine when all topics have only one partition but at soon as we define our topics with multiple partitions the lookup in the state store does not find the `string-value` for the given `string-key`. We suspected that was because `complex-type-key` and `string-key` are different types and such will be processed by different stream processors. Having the sate store local would make not possible to retrieve the `string-value` as in fact there would be one storage to save and a different one to look up. However we tried to convert the `complex-type-key` int the `string-key` and pass it `through` an internal topic with a key of type String  before saving to the state store.

This make me think our understanding about how all these state stores work is not clear and we are using it in a wrong way.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

**NOTE:**
We solved the issue by remapping `complex-type-key` into the `string-key` and storing it together with the `string-value` into an internal topic. Then when the response comes back we window `leftJoin` it with this internal topic. This way we gave up the usage of the state store entirely. However I still believe our initial approach was correct, providing it worked fine with one partition. It would still be good to understand what we done wrong. My feeling is that window left join solution has the two disadvantages of consuming more storage (costly in AWS) as well as an inaccurate window length can lead to loosing responses which could mean support calls

Comment: How many instances of the kafka streams application are running?

Comment: I believe it is only one. The problem can be easily reproduced using embedded Kafka integration test.

Comment: Can you share your test?

Comment: It is the same as the one explained on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402306/embedded-kafka-tests-randomly-failing with the only differences that now the number of partitions is 5 and there it was changed to address the random failing issue as per accepted response and attached comments